# Hello world/Console Project in Visual Studio 2008 64 bit

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, 64-bit, windows-7-x64

So I am trying to run console 64 bit Hello World program.

I have Windows 7 Enterprise x64 bit version.

I have installed Visual Studio 2008 and have added all of components needed for 64 bit.

I want to create simple console application.

It turns out to be a problem.

I have simple standard hello world project.

I have created it using New Project -> Empty project.
I added main.cpp that contains this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "howdy\n";
}
```

I added new configuration to the project by clicking on Config Manager and added x64 config.
Compiled and it compiles.

Tried running it and cmd.exe shoots up with following error:

"The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is in
correct. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.e
xe tool for more detail.
Press any key to continue . . .
"

Which set-up step if any I am missing.
What am I doing wrong and how should I go about setting simple console hello world in 64 bit world.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of starting with an Empty Project, choose a project of type "Console Application" in Visual Studio.

Comment: but that one is called win32 console app ?
i dont see why would that be the one for x64
but oh well it works so thanks

Comment: win32 is the name of the API that was developed for the first 32-bit windows. The 64-bit version is still called win32.